# jQuery addClass to every other html div class

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, addclass

I have a list of blog items (could be 10+) - see [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phil_joostrap/1advuptg/) which demo's just 4 items.

I am using Bootstrap and want to dynamically add a 'container' class to the 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc with jQuery - every other `<div class="item">` - so that I end up with the following:

```
<div class="blog">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1300x200/000000/fff" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="item container">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1300x200/000000/fff" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1300x200/000000/fff" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="item container">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1300x200/000000/fff" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I do this using the jQuery addClass ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".item:nth-child(even)").addClass("container");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kqr3o56r/

Comment: Can you further improve the answer rather the just _Try this:_?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop around as below:

```
$('.blog > .item:odd').each(function(key, value) {
    $(this).addClass('container');
  });
```

Refer to the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/s5hebh2y/).